# send individual parameters versus array of parameters

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a general good practice convention regarding sending parameters as individual variables, or to send an array of parameters to a function / method?

Eg.

```
param1, param2, param3 vs array data
```

How do you determine which of the two to use, or a combination of both?

Comment: send how, where, why, which language of the 2 you have tagged ?

Comment: Does that matter? I've been dealing with the same question in different languages, it's always a bit the same question.

Comment: This is more anecdote than answer, but (in JavaScript) multiple arguments is faster, because you're avoiding creating a superfluous `Array`. On the flip side, an `Array` could be seen as more expressive.

Comment: of course it matters. which screw should i use? no i wont tell you if im building a bookshelf or an oil tanker

Comment: Ok, if there is no generally accepted practice, I'll go with the individual parameters. Thanks.

Comment: i always pass an object containing all parameters(if there are many) instead of sending them individually.

Comment: My question is about maintainability majorly, not so much about speed. I wasn't sure which is considered best by experienced programmers. That's pretty much what my question is about. Perhaps that makes it clearer.

Comment: well, if you're making an API with a function that has a truckload of parameters, I'd just go with an object with named properties instead of even an array, unless it needs to be high performance. In javascript

Comment: If it is such a bad question receiving -1, then why is there an undubious, clear answer, deviating from some of your comments / other reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask about an array of arguments, I'm assuming you're talking about arguments that are all of the same type (or similar type).  It really depends upon the situation and it's a bit of a compromise between convenience for the caller and convenience for the function implementation.  That means a lot of it depends upon what you most want to optimize for. There are no hard and fast rules, but you can use this sort of thinking as guidance:

Use separate arguments if:

1. The number of arguments is relatively small and usually fixed
2. The code in the receiving function is much cleaner by having named arguments
3. The typical way the function call is made is not by building argument lists programatically

Use an array if:

1. The number of arguments is relatively large or usually variable (caller probably wants to build an array and pass that)
2. The receiving function is cleaner by processing a variable list of arguments in a loop (this can be done with the arguments object too, but is sometimes simpler with an actual array)
3. A common way that the function call is made is from a list of arguments that is built programmatically (more convenient for the caller to just be able to pass the array).
4. The called function wants to be able to easily pass the list of arguments to some other function call.  While this can be done without the array by processing the arguments object, it takes more code to do if the args aren't passed in an array to start with.

The caller can generally work-around either issue by using `.apply()` if the function isn't built to take an array, but the caller has arguments in an array.

---

FYI (though I don't think this was the main subject of your question), another option is to pass an object with a variable number of properties.  The options object is particularly useful when there are a number of different arguments and most or all are optional.  The called function can contain default values for all options and the caller can just pass the arguments they want to override the default for.  The options object generally isn't the best solution for a variable number of the same type of argument that is better represented in an array or as a list of arguments.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I wasn't sure, thanks again for confirming.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  What do you disagree with or think is wrong?  The OP seems to think it directly addressed their question.

Comment: I have different use cases, but I never bothered to ask the question. I always looked at the case in question and used what appeared to be the most logical to me. My question originated from the fact that there might be other developers who want to be able to identify the parameters taken by a method within seconds. In that case it would have appeared to me more logical to pass parameters individually if we're talking about eg. two or three.

Comment: @KimGysen - I agree that using named arguments in a function definition makes it more clear what the arguments are for that function (the code documents itself).  That is one of the considerations to balance, but of course, there are reasons to go down another path too sometimes.

Comment: Great, I understand the case differences, it's clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is that as soon as you have more than two parameters, you should switch to passing an aggregate of some sort (Array, Hash, Object, Record, whatever) instead.  If it's a case of one or two primary parameters and several options, then put just the options into an aggregate and keep the primaries in their own parameters.